# my data is not saving in database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

this is javacript  and ajax dont know what is error i tried this without ajax its working but with ajax not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#User_Name").val();
var email = $("#User_Email").val();
var mobno = $("#User_Email").val();
var landlineno = $("#user_MobileNo").val();
var proprTd = $("#propertyids").val();
var dataString = 'User_Name='+ name + 'User_Email=' + email + 'User_Email=' + mobno + 'user_MobileNo=' + landlineno + 'propertyids=' + proprTd;

if(name=='' || email=='' || mobno=='' || landlineno=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "SaveContactDetails.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

this is html code 
dont know what is error i tried this without ajax its working but with ajax not working.

```
<form method="post" name="form" >
<input type="hidden" name="propertyid" id="propertyids" value="<?php echo $Propid  ?>" >
                <input id="individual" name="rdoiam" value="individual" type="radio" class="input-38-ieo">
                Individual
                <input id="Agent" name="rdoiam" value="individual" type="radio" class="input-38-ieo">
                Agent
                <input id="builder" name="rdoiam" value="individual" type="radio" class="input-38-ieo">
                Builder <span id="ReqTypeErrorDiv12968081_left" class="span-41-ieo"></span> </li>
              <li class="li-42-ieo">
                <label class="label-43-ieo">Name<span class="span-37-ieo">*</span></label>
                :
                <input type="text" id="User_Name"  name="User_Name" maxlength="30" class="input-45-ieo11">
<input  type="text" class="input-276-ieo11" id="Mobileno" name="user_MobileNo"  maxlength="12">
<input  type="text" class="input-276-ieo11" id="userLandlineno" name="userLandlineno"  maxlength="12">
</form>
```

and this is php file

```
<?php
   include 'config.php';

    $iam ="";
    $User_Name="";
    $User_Email="";
     $user_MobileNo="";
     $user_LandlineNo="";
     $txtMessage="";
   if (isset($_POST['rdoiam']))
 {
 $iam =$_POST['rdoiam'];
 }

      if (isset($_POST['User_Name']))
 {
  $User_Name=$_POST['User_Name'];
 }
      if (isset($_POST['User_Email']))
 {
   $User_Email=$_POST['User_Email'];
 }
      if (isset($_POST['user_MobileNo']))
 {
  $user_MobileNo=$_POST['user_MobileNo'];
 }
          if (isset($_POST['userLandlineno']))
 {
 $user_LandlineNo=$_POST['userLandlineno'];
 }
 if(isset($_POST['txtMessage']))
 {

    $txtMessage=$_POST['txtMessage'];
 }


   $Propid=$_POST['propertyid'];




        $iam =trim($iam);
    $User_Name=trim($User_Name);
    $User_Email=trim($User_Email);
     $user_MobileNo=trim($user_MobileNo);
     $user_LandlineNo=trim($user_LandlineNo);
     $txtMessage=trim($txtMessage);


$str="Call sp_SaveContactDetails('".$iam."','".$User_Name."','".$User_Email."','".$user_MobileNo."','".$user_LandlineNo."','".$txtMessage."','".$Propid."')";

   // $sql=mysql_query($str);
    if(!mysql_query($str)) 
{ 
 die('Error:'.mysql_error()); 
 } 
 else 

 { 







  }
     ?>
```

Comment: Add an error handler to the ajax call, is it triggered. Set beak points, are the values what you expect?

Comment: @user2092317, that is incorrect...

Comment: You are missing `&` in your data string, as I said in my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `&` in your data string:

```
var dataString = 'User_Name='+ name + 'User_Email=' + email + 'User_Email=' + mobno + 'user_MobileNo=' + landlineno + 'propertyids=' + proprTd;
```

It has to be:

```
var dataString = 'User_Name='+ name + '&User_Email=' + email + '&User_Email=' + mobno + '&user_MobileNo=' + landlineno + '&propertyids=' + proprTd;
```

Thats why its not sending proper data, as you want. Of course, you can serialize all your data...

Also you should be using encodeURIComponent because if the user adds a & or =, your string is going to break.

Answer (score -1):

```
var dataString = 'User_Name='+ name + 'User_Email=' + email + 'User_Email=' + mobno + 'user_MobileNo=' + landlineno + 'propertyids=' + proprTd;
```

That is not how you build a querystring

The string looks like `User_Name=nameUser_Email=email....`, you are missing the `&` between each. Also you should be using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) because if the user adds a & or =, your string is going to break.

Look at jQuery [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) it does all of it for you.

Comment: how can i post all data to php.

Comment: you are welcome.. @epascarello just edit his answer, and copy from mine, that you are missing `&`, LOL...

Answer (score -1):

Or just use `serialize` function, you are using jQuery anyway.

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = $( this ).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SaveContactDetails.php",
    data: formData,
    success: function(){
      $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
      $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Before sending ajax you can always add your validation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
  <script>
        $(function () {
            $('form#person').on('submit', function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'show.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });     
    </script>
```