# PHP POST data array is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am using HTML, PHP and AJAX to create a search field.
Here is my HTML Code:

```
<form action="search.php" id="search_form" method="post" >
    <div class="search_bar">
    <input type="text"  name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search anything" >
    </div>
    <div class="search_button">
    <button type="submit" id="search_button"  name="search_submit" >Search</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is my AJAX Code:

```
$('#search_button').click(function(event) {

    var search_data = $('#search_text').val();

    var postData ={
            "content":search_data};

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'search.php',
        data:{myData: postData},
        error: function()
        {
           alert("Request Failed");
        },
        success: function(response)
        {        
            alert("Success");
        }
    });

});
```

In PHP I tried the following:

```
$obj = $_POST['myData'];
echo $obj;
print_r($_POST);
```

All I am getting is:

> Notice: Undefined index: myData in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\MakeMyApp\WebContent\search.php on line 9

```
Array ( )
```

I have also tried with:

```
file_get_contents('php //input')
```

but there also I am getting empty array. I don't know what exactly the problem is. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: If you remove the AJAX from the equation, do the PHP work?

Comment: Never assume a `$_POST` super is set. Check to make sure it exists before accessing it.

Comment: Have you checked your request header `Content-Type` (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [my data is not saving in database using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590289/my-data-is-not-saving-in-database-using-ajax)

Comment: If you want to use ajax, just don't use a form with a submit button.

Comment: Try `<pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>` as the first line to check what are received at server side.

Comment: Then check your ajax with developer tools included with the browser

Comment: I am getting nowhere with all the answers...please tell me what should I do next?

Comment: @RakehSahu start by inspecting the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is actually sent. Then as mentioned do a dump of `$_POST` without looking for `myData`. You need to isolate the problem better. Also make sure there are no other errors in console that would cause form to submit by default process. Is your jQuery wrapped in `document.ready`?

Comment: I have also used "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as "contentType" but no success!!

Comment: Also where are you seeing this errror? In the browser during a page reload? If so your event code probably isn't even being bound to the button

Comment: I shown you here the correct solution, which I tested and it was working...

Comment: In Browser it is correctly displaying the array as 
Array ( [myData] => Array ( [content] => rakesh) )
What should I do next?

Comment: @Legionar changing data to string has no relevance on the problem. Passing object is most common practice

Comment: @Legionar where is your answer? I don't see anything!!

Comment: In Browser Network under search.php it is correctly showing the data. But then again there is this-"search.php?=1447082493882". Any idea what this might be??

Comment: @RakehSahu its timestamp of your request.

Comment: @Legionar then why is data empty at that particular timestamp? Data is shown correctly before that timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't comment as I don't have enough 'reputation'.

I have tried to replicate your issue and it seems to work ok for me.

Here is the HTML page ...

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search_button').click(function(event) {

    var search_data = $('#search_text').val();

    var postData ={
            "content":search_data};

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'search-submit.php',
        data:{myData: postData},
        error: function()
        {
           alert("Request Failed");
        },
        success: function(response)
        {        
            alert(response);
        }
    });

});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" id="search_form" method="post" >
    <div class="search_bar">
    <input type="text"  name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search anything" >
    </div>
    <div class="search_button">
    <button type="submit" id="search_button"  name="search_submit" >Search</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the receiving PHP page

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

In the ajax request, you can see I'm using alert to output the response in an alert but, and if all goes well it should output the content outputted by the receiving PHP page.

Also, it may not help much, but his is how I would have done the ajax request; it's slightly less code and you don't have to define each form field individually (if you have more than one field)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search_form').submit(function() {
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'search-submit.php',
        data: formData,
        error: function()
        {
           alert("Request Failed");
        },
        success: function(response)
        {        
            alert(response);
        }

    });

    return false;

});

});
```

Comment: so what can be the possible error in my code?? or is it other error?? like file configuration??

Comment: Can you tell me how you know that the request isn't being submitted correctly? have you tried alerting the response as I have done above? I suspect your form is working correctly, but you can't see the output.

Comment: I added an alert for the response. Surprisingly I am getting the correct response in alert but not from PHP file

Comment: ok, I think you're failing to understand how the ajax request works. What you are doing is submitting the data to the PHP page in the 'background', that means you won't be able to physically see what the PHP is retrieving. If you completely remove all of your javascript from the page, you should see that the form submits to the search.php page, and it will output what it has received. There is nothing wrong with your code, it's just that I don't feel you understand it.

Comment: Also, the response you see in the alert, is the output from the PHP file. The PHP file receives the form submission, and the output of the form is returned to your ajax method in a variable called 'response', which you are outputting in an alert.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say...the PHP is returning correct daa array response which is being alerted...but after that data array is again becoming empty

Comment: It's empty when? PHP won't hold that information forever. If you submit the form, and then visit your search.php file in your browser, it won't remember what it received. If you want it to be remembered you could use a session. It might be worthwhile explaining what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: without using Ajax, i am still getting empty array in PHP.. can you help ?

Comment: You shouldn't get an empty array. When you press the submit button the page should change to the search.php and the output will show exactly what the alert(response) was showing, the reason being is the alert(response) shows the output from the PHP file upon form submission. Can you tell us what it is you are trying to do?